# sqlite3 cast REAL as NUMERIC(x,y)

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with a numeric(6,4) column (x.xxxx)
In the select statement, I have to do math on this column which results in the value being typed as a REAL. I need to display the results using numeric(6,4) though and can't seem to see how to do this.
I tried "cast(column as numeric(6,4))" which works in other databases, but the displayed value is still REAL format with more than 4 digits to the right of the decimal. I need to get it back to the "x.xxxx" format from REAL.